# Carousel boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this piece of code:

```
<div class="body">
   <div class="grid">
       <div class="item-grid">
           <div class="list">
               <div class="item-list">
                   <div class="item">

                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What i need to realize is a simple carousel that show at last 4 "item" concurrently. The actual css class I need it for some javascript that load data.

I can use bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: You can search on google and you will find a lot of js plugin

Comment: Is this all you need? Are you sure you need only the CSS? Maybe a full working back-end system for your website? I think it's too less what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library has been very useful for my projects: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: Nice, I will try this lib. Thanks.